# Normalization the table to 3NF

Tags: database, database-design, normalization

I have trouble in understanding how do I represent the foreign key after I normalize the table to 3NF.

Lets consider the table this way:

```
student(studentid,studentname,courseid,coursename,dateofexam,marks,grade)
```

I can able to figure out the FD as follows:

```
studentid -> studentname
courseid -> coursename
{student,courseid} -> dateofexam,marks
marks -> grade
```

Now I'm trying to create a new table for FD that has non-ket attributes like this:

```
marks grade
studentid studentname
```

Now how do I relate the foreign key for these tables with my old table `student`? I'm confused on doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the difference between a mark and a grade?

Answer (score 1):

Your FD actually shows you how:

```
studentid -> studentname
courseid -> coursename
{student,courseid} -> dateofexam,marks
marks -> grade
```

Each row would be a separate table.
The keys that exists in other tables would be the fk.
In this case:

```
{student,courseid} -> dateofexam,marks
```

that would be studentid, courseid and marks(which probably must be an id too)

It would be something like this

Student(
studentid,
studentname)

Course(
courseid,
coursename)

Exams(
examid,
fk_studentid,
fk_courseid,
dateofexam,
fk_markid)

Marks(
markid,
grades)

Comment: There's no need for "marks" to be an id number. ID numbers have nothing to do with normalization. When you're talking about how to normalize a relation, you're generally *not* allowed to introduce new columns (as you did with "examid" in exams); just use what you start with. For the table you named "Exams", the key would be {studentid, courseid}.